# Unable to Modify Link Text

Tags: posts

I've somehow managed to disable URL text control on a site. The two images below show a post with a URL on two sites, on one I have no ability to change the displayed text other than by editing the HTML directly.

I can see in the CSS that the site with control has the class 'has-text-control' in the master div.

Does anyone know how to re-enable this?

[image: Without text control]

[image: With text control]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't disabled it, one of those screenshots is taken on an older version of WordPress and the block editor that didn't have a link text box.

Look at the toolbar and you'll see the icons for the link in the toolbar are not the same.

Additionally, you don't need the link text box to change the link text. The text is directly editable:

[image]

Click on the text and start typing/deleting, or use the arrow keys to navigate to it the same way you would do it in any word processor or notepad application. The popup box with the link text box is there purely to make things easier, it's not the only way to change it or even the preferred method.

If you need that particular specific method though, upgrade WordPress.